# Static int array elements become 0 when accessed from another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static, fragment

I have 2 fragments (OCR.java and Manual.java). Both fragments are under MainActivity. In the fragment in Manual.java, I initialised a public static 2d int array `public static int[][] board = new int[9][9]`. I then went on to change the value of `board` from the fragment in OCR.java. I ran a `Log.i` in OCR.java to check value of `board` and it is updated.

However, when i went on to retrieve the value of `board` in the fragment in Manual.java, the elements in the array are all 0.

1) Why is this happening?
2) Shouldnt public static values retain their values even across classes?
3) Is there a better way to do what I want to achieve? Which actually can be simplified to just passing a 2d int array from one fragment in a class to another fragment in another class.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

**MainActivity.class**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static int board[][] = new int[9][9];
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}
```

**OCR.java**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ocr, container, false);

    ...


                        for (int row = 0; row < indiGrids.length; row ++) {
                            for (int col = 0; col < indiGrids[row].length; col ++) {

                                ...

                                    try {
                                        board[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(getText(indiGrids[row][col]));
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                        board[row][col] = 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    board[row][col] = 0;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        Log.wtf("Board", "" + board[0][1]); //returns 4, because i just set it in the above nested for loop.
                    } ...


    return rootView;
}
```

**Manual.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manual, container, false);
 Log.wtf("TEST", "" + board[0][1]); // returns 0, instead of 4
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't modifying the value?
Try to write 'public static int[][] board = new int[9][9]' in the Main Activity if you are sure you don't override it.

Comment: I have tried putting `public static int[][] board = new int[9][9]` in MainActivity, then in OCR.java, i set the values of the elements of`board` using a nested for loop. Checked the values of `board` in OCR.java after that and sure enough, the values are updated.

However, when i check the values of `board` in Manual.java, all the elements in `board` are 0.

Comment: share relevant code

Comment: updated post with code from all 3 classes. hope it is clearer now. thanks @user10844401

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the array by passing through Bundle and set it to the fragment with **setArguments** method.

**To pass:**

```
bundle.putSerializable("array", board); // Here bundle is Bundle object.
```

**To retrieve:**

```
iny[][] boardAtOtherSide = (int[][]) getArguments().getSerializable("array"); //Use this inside OCR fragment
```

**To set:**

```
OCR ocr = new OCR();//Use this same instance to change fragment
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("array", board);
ocr.setArguments(mBundle);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! Yup I think this is a good way to parse data between fragments. Found out the issue in my project. Nothing to do with data parsed, but fragment initialisations! Thank you nonetheless though.